# On Team Viewer, how can I maximize remote computer's screen?

Tags: teamviewer

See screen shot under neath...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CaldeiraG](https://superuser.com/questions/1495650/on-team-viewer-how-can-i-maximize-remote-computers-screen?noredirect=1#comment2257305_1495650) commented

> Usually whenever that happens is because the remote computer has a lower resolution than your computer. You can go to the View Tab > Scaling > Full screen to fix it.

[image]